# How to parse multiple feeds from csv file with feedparser?

Tags: python, pandas, feedparser

I'm trying to parse multiple feeds (500) from the list in CSV file and save results to another CSV file. Problem is that parser go over only one feed in the list.

```
writer = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'w'))
reader = csv.reader(open('feeds.csv', 'r'))
next(reader) # skip column headings

for row in reader:
    url = row[0]
    print (url)
df = pd.DataFrame(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['author', 'title', 'link','summary', 'published'])
for i, post in enumerate(feed.entries):
    df.loc[i] = post.author, post.title, post.link, post.summary, post.published

df
```

CSV file looks like this 
[image: CSV List feeds.cav]

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve my problem here is the final code if someone will have a similar problem in future

```
import feedparser
import csv
import pandas as pd

reader = csv.reader(open('feeds.csv', 'r'))
next(reader) # column headings
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['author', 'title', 'link','summary', 'published'])
for row in reader:
    url = row[0]
    print (url)

    feed = feedparser.parse(url)

    for i, post in enumerate(feed.entries):
        df.loc[len(df)] = post.author, post.title, post.link, post.summary, post.published

df.to_csv('myfilename.csv', index=False)
```